# How to select articles by condition in local scope?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have `Article` model and `Country` model with specified relationships amid:

**Article**

```
public function country(){
    return $this-has_one("Country);
}
```

I need to get Articles where country is "USA", for this I do:

```
Articles:with("country")->get();
```

It returns me all articles with related countries.

How to assign local scope for `with("country")` that to set additional condition?

I tried:

```
 public function scopeLocation($query)
    {
        $country_name = Location::get());
        if(!empty($country_name)){
             return $query->where('name', '=', $country_name);
       }
    }
```

But I dont know how to call that in `with`

Comment: What's does Location mean here sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. You don't need to use local scope here, you don't need to use `with()` here and you didn't define the relationship correctly.

First, add `country_id` field to the `articles` table and define the relationship:

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Country');
}
```

Then use simple query to get all articles by country ID:

```
$articles = Article::where('country_id', $countryId)->get();
```

If you don't know country ID, but you know country name, use `whereHas()`:

```
$articles = Article::whereHas('country', function($q) use($countryName) {
    $q->where('name', $countryName);
})->get();
```

Comment: Very weird, but I have: `$announcements = Article::with("country00")`. So in Article model there is not method `country00`. It does not call error, why?